# State changes but component doesn't update - ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, state, render

I'm using ionic with angular, when i'm creating alert in ok button's callback function i'm changing my state. State changes, but this change doesn't effects in iu, i think component is not updating. How can I fix this?

```
async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: '',
      message: '',
      buttons: [
        'cancel',
        {
          text: 'ok',
          handler: () => {
            this.currentScreen = "";
            this.dates[this.currentDateIndex].isOrdered = false;//disable order
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the full component code? It's a little hard to tell what's going on here  without understanding the full context - namely, how is your component configured via its decorator, what calls presentAlert(), what the alertController is/does, etc etc.

Comment: I don't see a state change in there, is this the function that updates state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `ChangeDetectorRef` to explicitly state that change has been made and view needs to be updated.

Reference: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Example:

Declare ChangeDetectorRef in constructor

```
constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Then use it in your callback:

```
buttons: [
    'cancel',
    {
      text: 'ok',
      handler: () => {
        this.currentScreen = "";
        this.dates[this.currentDateIndex].isOrdered = false;//disable order
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    }
  ]
```